# Why do I get the kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported (10868) error?

Tags: ios, core-audio

This has to be the most cryptic error in core audio that I've encountered. When I sent a format on an output of an audio unit, why do I get this error?

Is it because the audio unit does support the stream format I'm using, or is it because the platform (namely iOS) I'm on doesn't support the format?

If it's the former does each audio unit only support a specific format? If so, where do I find that information?

I'm trying to build an intuitive understanding of audio units and audio graphs. It mostly makes sense but the stream format are infuriatingly cryptic.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it because the audio unit does support the stream format I'm using, or is it because the platform (namely iOS) I'm on doesn't support the format?

Probably the AU -- what's returning the error code? `AudioUnitSetProperty`?

> …does each audio unit only support a specific format? If so, where do I find that information?

An AU can support multiple formats. You have to ask the AU what formats it supports (which can vary by version). AUs built for a certain platform (e.g. OS X or iOS) typically support the 'canonic' format of the OS, and may support others. The canonic format varies by platform. On OS X, AUs rarely deviate from the canonic format (deinterleaved `float` PCM);

Also verify that you're setting up the format correctly -- can you init *any* AU on iOS with that format, or is just one giving you trouble? How's it defined? Is it the canonic format of the OS? If the format you want is really necessary, you may need a format conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The audio units support different formats on different platforms.  You can query the audio units by trying a format and checking for the format not supported error 
message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: '[[busArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)element] setFormat:format error:&nsErr]: returned false, error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10868 "(null)"'

check from [osstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=10868)

**kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported**

I use not interleaved:

```
public var readFormat: AVAudioFormat {
    return AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: false)!
}
```

instead of

```
public var readFormat: AVAudioFormat {
    return AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: true)!
}
```

,then OK